# Apostrophe CMS - afterInsert is called multiple times

Tags: javascript, node.js, apostrophe-cms

In Apostrophe CMS I have a piece that I wish to be submitable using `apostrophe-submit-widgets` - and everything seems to be working, except that my afterInsert method is called twice and thus sends twice the amount of emails.

My configuration looks like this:

```js
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')
const colors = require('colors')

module.exports = {
  extend: 'apostrophe-pieces',
  name: 'request-form',
  label: 'Request Form',
  alias: 'requestForm',
  //...
  ],
  construct: function (self, options) {
    self.beforeSave = function (req, piece, options, callback) {
      piece.title = piece.name + ' ' + piece.email
      piece.published = true
      return callback()
    }
    self.afterInsert = async function (req, piece, options, callback) {
      const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        //transport config
      });

      function handleError(err) {
        console.error(err.cyan)
        return callback(err)
      }

      const messageToAdmin = {
        //nodemailer message config
      }


      const messageToUser = {
        //nodemailer message config
      }

      await transporter.sendMail(messageToAdmin)
        .then(transporter.sendMail(messageToUser))
        .catch(handleError)

      return callback()
    }
  }
}
```

Do you have any idea why it might be working like that? The only thing that I was able to find out with debug tools is that the afterInsert is indeed called twice, it's not something inside it that's looped.
It happens both when I use `request-forms-submit-widgets` and when I add it from the admin bar.

Edit: As per suggestion I removed `then` chaining and used instead this:

```js
try {
  await transporter.sendMail(messageToAdmin)
  await transporter.sendMail(messageToUser)
  callback()
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err)
  callback(err)
}
```

Unfortunately, it did not help.

Comment: Please try cleaning up your async/await syntax first. You should never have to mix "then" with async/await. "await" the first sendMail call, and on the next line "await" the second one. After the second "await" line, you can just invoke the callback and that's the end. Then wrap a "try/catch" around the entire body of the function and, in the catch block, pass the error to `callback`. Let me know if that helps and if not we can look into it further.

Comment: @TomBoutell I had it written as a regular callback-based function at the beginning, this was a kinda messy search for suspects. I removed then() as you suggested (edit in the main post), alas it helped not.

Comment: OK thanks for ruling it out.

Comment: Have you checked whether `beforeSave` is also called twice?

Comment: If you are using workflow, and have not marked the type as exempt from workflow, it would be called once for each locale.

Comment: @TomBoutell That was exactly it! Excluding it from apostrophe-workflow made it work perfectly. Thank you so much! If you could post it as an answer I would gladly mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `apostrophe-workflow`, you can expect more than one call to `afterInsert` because the document must be inserted separately into each locale.

If you are not using localization, you might wonder why this is necessary. The answer is that ordinary edit/submit/commit workflow still uses two locales, called `default` and `default-draft`.

If workflow is appropriate for the content that is being submitted, for instance it will be further edited as a draft before it is approved and committed, then you should account for this in your `afterInsert` handler. You can look at `piece.workflowLocale` to figure out which locale you're dealing with.

If workflow is not necessary for this content type, just add it to the `excludeTypes` array option in your configuration of the `apostrophe-workflow` module. Just one thing to keep in mind there: types excluded from workflow cannot `join` with types that do have workflow. However you can do the reverse (types with workflow can join with types that are excluded). This restriction will likely be lifted in 3.x.